# Regex to get phone number if line contains

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am a marketer I am making some regex to scrape phone number using a tool. I have the following regex which scrape phone number of XXX-XXX-XXXX format perfectly. Here the issue is the page having numbers in more than 6 different lines but I want to scrape only if the line contains `<span no="telephone">`

```
((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}
```

I have tried getting the phone number between the strings some how because of source code of that page that way is not working properly I just want to give a try with the new way.

My page source is always like

```
<a href="/phone/xxx-xxx-xxxx"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Mobile" >
            <span itemprop="telephone">xxx-xxx-xxxx</span>
```

How I can achieve this. Really appreciate your help. Make sure I have scrape after the tags `<span itemprop="telephone">`

Comment: Say what now? *is the page having numbers in more than 6 different lines* ??

Comment: Hey I edited my question. The page having 6 phone numbers but I want to scrape only if that line contains <span no="telephone">

Comment: You might want to look at using some other method than regex. How about using some xml/html parser like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I am not coding any tool  I am using existing tool. I don't think beautifulsoup integrate with my tool. It having only few options. Give me a sec I will upload the image. https://i.postimg.cc/7ZcCwnY0/Screenshot-from-2018-11-27-22-25-15.png

Comment: I strongly recommend you visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can reformat your question in a manner that may be answerable.

Comment: didnt somebody once say something wise about parsing html with regexes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
@"(?<=<span itemprop=""telephone"">)((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}(?=</span>)"
```

The regex starts by creating a `look behind`, looking for: `'<span itemprop="telephone">'`

Then it uses the regex you already have to match a telehone number.

Finally it uses a `look ahead`, looking for: '`</span>`' to finish the match.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood correctly you want to know if the number in the `<span no="telephone">`is a viable phone number using regex? If that is the case the below will spit out 123-456-7891 is it matches your string pattern

```
string[] phoneNumber = lineContainingNumber.Split('>');

        foreach (string phoneNumberEntity in phoneNumber)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(phoneNumberEntity.Replace(@"</span", ""), @"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(phoneNumberEntity.Replace(@"</span", ""));
                break;
            }

        }
```